# Why does Gnome System Monitor Network Graph always show '0 bits/s' as a regular user?

Tags: gnome, system-monitor, network-monitoring

I am using gnome-system-monitor installed with Ubuntu 20.04, and the network graph always shows '0 bits/s', whereas the system-monitor extension (the one in my top bar) shows my actual network usage. The network graph sending line also incorrectly flashes (suddenly changes into a few vertical lines).

EDIT 0: It works fine when I run with sudo, but how can I fix that?

Always says '0 bits/s':
[image: Always says '0 bits/s']

The yellow sending graph suddenly turns into vertical lines every secondish:
[image: The yellow sending graph suddenly turns into vertical lines every secondish.]

Comment: Why do you run it with sudo?

Comment: @mikewhatever I just ran it with sudo to test if the network graph appeared correctly. And it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed for me in Ubuntu 20.10.